# Moving ADO servers and agent machines to a different location

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

We are fixing to move our ADO build servers and a number of deploy agent machines to a different location with a different set of IPs for each machine.

Is there a recommended approach to moving these machines that allow them to keep working or do we need to reinstall the agents on all the machines picking up new IP addresses?

Is there something easier that can be done on each agent to allow them to start working without reinstalling agents?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly what you asking for, as far as I know, and researched, there is no easy way. You need to install agents on new servers.

Comment: did you also have to reinstall or reconfigure all your deployment group agents or where they able to start up and communicate back to dev.azure.com?

we have probably 30 deployment group agents installed so hoping these will just work after we move the machines to new IPs

Comment: Everything is working most of thing are move manually. If the server that host the agent is the same then it is matter of re installing the agent but in my work place I ended to create new server to ensure the old agents works until all was move it took me longer time

Comment: I would suggest you make POC on one of them and make some learning and document your steps

Comment: I can provide the steps in my answer if you want let me know